# Phaser game preload not running in simple example

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_breakout_game_Phaser/Scaling), and... I haven't gotten very far.

My code is below, exactly as the example.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(480, 320, Phaser.AUTO, null, {preload: preload, create: create, update: update});

function preload() {
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
    game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#eee';
}
function create() {}
function update() {}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://end3r.github.io/Gamedev-Phaser-Content-Kit/demos/js/phaser.2.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

This code works great here and in jsfiddle, but for some reason I cannot explain, it does not work when I run it locally. I see the canvas, but none of the preload code runs. the background is black and it is not aligned. It doesnt matter what browser I use. Why would this be?

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors when you run it locally?

Comment: No errors at all, which is the most frustrating part...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. I'm instantiating Phaser.Game from the `mounted` method in a Vue component. It's working fine aside from none of the game's state events are firing :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, in version 3 the config option changed from `state` to `scene`. Check out the docs here: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/

Answer (score -1):

you need

```
this.scale.forcePortrait = true;
```

should be so

```
function preload() {
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
    game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
    this.scale.forcePortrait = true;
   game.stage.backgroundColor = '#eee';
}
```